# sphinx: Is there a way to embed everything in a single html page?

Tags: python-sphinx

in sphinx, is there a way to embed css and js in a single html page (I mean not manually) ?
I tried to search around on internet but I didn't find anything.
thanks

Comment: I don't see any way of doing this with the standard Sphinx distribution. Of the sphinx extensions I know there's none aimed at doing this. Given the HTML changes depending on the theme you are using, the best bet is probably using `make singlehtml` and writing a script to append the CSS and JS files from `_static` to the top of the HTML file.

Comment: What do you mean by "embed"? Using an iframe? Displaying a code sample? Adding static assets to the page either in the `<head>` or elsewhere?

Comment: @bad_coder yeah, sphinx can't do that, the only way is make a script with awk or sed to embed it.

Comment: @StevePiercy I mean put the css and js inside the html page.

Comment: @BiosRootKit you might find some tool that does that merge automatically. I suppose someone has thought of this before without using Sphinx.

Comment: You could either specify external assets in your `conf.py` or modify your theme's templates. For the former (and easier method) see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files and https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_js_files.

Comment: @BiosRootKit do you mean complete single file HTML without external files - inline <script>s, <style>s, and images and fonts as data URI all in one HTML file?

Comment: @matt would be the best, yes.